# Why can't I set up my Kalabox Drupal Site? SQLState[Hy000] error

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-8

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 in Hyper-V, a fresh install of mysql and user 'root'@'localhost' with 'password'. I created a database called 'drupaltest'. Yet when I start up a kalabox Drupal Site, I try enter that information in and I get this error:

Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory.

Can you help me figure out what's going on with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the related information to your question [here](http://php.kalabox.io/en/stable/users/cli/).  From this you find your database related information following these steps:

1. Use the *Terminal* option from the dropdown to access the location of the PHP app that you already created.  In this example it is the second option for the existing new Drupal 8 installation.
   [image]
2. This will open the terminal navigated to the kalabox container.  confirm that it is in the parent directory. Check for the kalabox root files and directories; cli.yml, code, config, dockerfiles, etc..  They should resemble something like this:
   [image]
   You can see that the kalabox container is located in my user directory.
3. use the `kbox services` command to print the services available to the container.  If it doesn't work you may not be in the parent directory of the container and would refer back to step 2.
   [image]

Comment: Hey! Mike Pirog helped me in person, and I forgot about this :/ BUT I'm very glad you put it here, in case someone else is experiencing the same problems. Although Mike did recommend I just channel into an existing Pantheon Site since Pantheon creates a lot of the background stuff that I would have to manually add.

Comment: Sure no problem @user3654055. I was actually looking for a solution myself and found this question.  After solving it I decided that it needs a more complete answer.  Thanks for asking it :D

Answer (score 1):

use the mysql database that comes with your kalabox site!

Comment: how? I'm in the middle of setup and it's asking for this information. Where do I get it from?